# Is it possible to compare one variable to several other variables in a if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I would like to improve this following if statement

```
#Extract ORG, GPE, LOC and FAC labels from phrases
for entity in doc.ents:
    if entity.label_ == "ORG" or entity.label_ == "GPE" or entity.label_ == "LOC" or entity.label_ == "FAC":
        print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

Is it possible reduce the number of "entity.label_" variables to one?

Comment: `if entity.label_ in ('ORG', 'GPE', 'LOC', 'FAC'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check if `entity.label_` var in a tuple of all the words.

```
for entity in doc.ents:
    if entity.label_ in ("ORG", "GPE", "LOC", "FAC"):
        print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for entity in doc.ents:
    if any(entity.label_ == x for x in ["ORG", "GPE", "LOC", "FAC"]):
        print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```